# logstash error while starting -- LoadError: Could not load FFI Provider:

Tags: logstash, jruby

I installed latest Logstash (2.4) on my linux mint 17.  Created a conf file and tried starting it.  It gives me a very huge stack trace (1740 lines of stack trace).

```
LoadError: Could not load FFI Provider: (NotImplementedError) FFI not available: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not locate stub library in jar file.  Tried [jni/x86_64-Linux/libjffi-१.२.so, /jni/x86_64-Linux/libjffi-१.२.so]
        at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.getStubLibraryStream(StubLoader.java:396)
        at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.loadFromJar(StubLoader.java:345)
        at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.load(StubLoader.java:254)
        at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.<clinit>(StubLoader.java:434)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.kenai.jffi.Init.load(Init.java:68)
        at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.getInstanceHolder(Foreign.java:49)
        at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign$InstanceHolder.<clinit>(Foreign.java:45)
        at com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.getInstance(Foreign.java:103)
        at com.kenai.jffi.Platform.isSupported(Platform.java:370)
```

I am reproducing above, first few lines of stack trace.

Some part of the stack trace (added below here) seems to suggest, it got something to do with jruby.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64/libjffi-१.२.so
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.loadFromBootPath(StubLoader.java:316)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.load(StubLoader.java:249)
    at com.kenai.jffi.internal.StubLoader.<clinit>(StubLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

Any clues or recommendations on how to proceed to fix this..?

As shown in the 2nd stack trace above, my m/c doesn't have a directory /usr/java/..., so its obviously failing.  But I don't understand why it will look for /usr/java/... set of folders.

Some other part of stack trace shows it is unable to locate libjffi-1.2.so.

What do all these errors mean, and how to fix ?

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem with the jre you are using. Logstash requires java 7.

Comment: I am using java 8. Doesn't it work with java8?

Comment: It should work for java 8. It was just an idea and it was wrong

Comment: @MupparthyRavindranath Logstash 2.4 only need Java 7 or later from the documentation of logstash.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this either by in jvm.options:
-Djava.io.tmpdir=</some/tmp/dir>

Where </some/tmp/dir> is a temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

Modify "LS_JAVA_OPTS" option in /etc/sysconfig/logstash file  as given below:

#vim /etc/sysconfig/logstash
...
#LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME"
#LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=$HOME"
LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/logstash"
...

"Djava.io.tmpdir" can be set to any directory of your preference instead of "/var/lib/logstash".

[root@psj ELK]# service logstash status
logstash is running

it work for me. I found it an another blog
root link: http://pradyumnajoshi.blogspot.com/2015/04/logstash-loaderror-could-not-load-ffi.html